# Is there any way to control RGB of CoolerMaster fans from ubuntu?

Tags: drivers

I have CoolerMaster MasterLiquid ML240L RGB V2. I did some googling, and found things like OpenRGB, but this device is not explicitly listed. Just wondering if there is a way to change the RGB settings that I missed. I can change it using a physical controller, but it sits inside the case, and the colors are reset every time I reboot the computer. I'm using Kubuntu 23.04.